# Call child function from parent component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm developing my first React Native app. What I'm trying to achieve is to execute a child function from the parent component, this is the situation:

**Child**

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  ...
  myfunct: function() {
    console.log('Managed!');
  }
  ...
  render(){
    return(
      <Listview
      ...
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  ...
  execChildFunct: function() {
    ...
    //launch child function "myfunct"
    ...
    //do other stuff
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this.execChildFunct} />
        <Child {...this.props} />
      </View>);
  }
}
```

In this example, I would like to log `'Managed!'` when I press the button in the parent class. How is it feasible?

Answer (score 35):

Here's how you can do this with functional components:

**Parent**

1. Use `useRef()` to give the child component a reference in the parent:

```js
const childRef = useRef()
// ...
return (
   <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
)
...
```

**Child**

1. Pass `ref` as one of the constructor parameters:

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  // ...
}
```

2. Import `useImperativeHandle` and `forwardRef` methods from the `'react'` library:

```js
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react'
```

3. Use `useImperativeHandle` to bind functions to the `ref` object, which will make these functions accessible to the parent

These methods won't be internally available, so you may want to use them to call internal methods.

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  //...
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // each key is connected to `ref` as a method name
    // they can execute code directly, or call a local method
    method1: () => { localMethod1() },
    method2: () => { console.log("Remote method 2 executed") }
  }))
  //...
  
  // These are local methods, they are not seen by `ref`,
  const localMethod1 = () => {
    console.log("Method 1 executed")
  }
  // ..
}
```

4. Export the child component using `forwardRef`:

```js
const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  // ...
}
export default forwardRef(ChildComponent)
```

### Putting it all together

**Child Component**

```js
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'


const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // methods connected to `ref`
    sayHi: () => { sayHi() }
  }))
  // internal method
  const sayHi = () => {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
  return (
    <View />
  );
}

export default forwardRef(ChildComponent)
```

**Parent Component**

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent';

const App = () => {
  const childRef = useRef()
  return (
    <View>
      <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          childRef.current.sayHi()
        }}
        title="Execute Child Method"
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

There is an interactive demo of this on Expo Snacks:
https://snack.expo.dev/@backupbrain/calling-functions-from-other-components

This explanation is modified from this [TutorialsPoint article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs-useimperativehandle-hook)

Comment: it says TypeError: undefined is not an object

Answer (score 34):

Nader Dabit's answer is outdated, since using String literals in ref attributes [has been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs). This is how we would do it as of September 2017:

```
<Child ref={child => {this.child = child}} {...this.props} />
<Button onPress={this.child.myfunc} />
```

Same functionality, but instead of using a String to reference the component, we store it in a global variable instead.

Answer (score 26):

You can add a ref to the child component:

```
<Child ref='child' {...this.props} />
```

Then call the method on the child like this:

```
<Button onPress={this.refs.child.myfunc} />
```

Comment: But `execChildFunct` has to do also other things: can I call `this.refs.child.myfunct` in `execChildFunct`? Because I tried and it didn't work :/

Answer (score 8):

***it is in react. i hope it may help you.***

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(null)
  }
  method() {
    console.log('do stuff')
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  }
}
```

---

```
class EnhancedChild extends React.Component {
        render() {
        return <Child {...this.props} />
      }
    }

class Parent extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    this.child.method() // do stuff
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <EnhancedChild onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Child.method()</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Original Solution:**

https://jsfiddle.net/frenzzy/z9c46qtv/

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909

Comment: what is this.child??

Comment: In the `<EnhancedChild />` we have an `onRef={ref=>(this.child = ref)}`, meaning that we set `this.child` to the `ref` variable.

Or said another way, `this.child` is a reference to the `<EnhancedChild />` instance.

Answer (score 7):

Simple and easy way to Parent --> Child function call

```
/* Parent.js */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  onChildClick = () => {
    this.child.childFunction(); // do stuff
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onRef={(ref) => (this.child = ref)} />
        <TouchableOpacity onClick={this.onChildClick}>
          <Text>Child</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/* Child.js */
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }
  childFunction() {
    // do stuff
    alert("childFunction called");
  }
  render() {
    return <View>Hello World!</View>;
  }
}
```

**Original Solution:**
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909

Answer (score 4):

I think you have misunderstood something about component structure.

Assume that your child is a component which generates button for your other components. In this hierarchy your child has to inform it's parent that it was pressed.

child -----> parent

```
export default class Child extends Component {

     return(
    <Button onPress={this.props.onPress } />
     );
  }
```

In your parent component use child component to generate a button for you. In this way you can use child component any other components as a independent button.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.execChildFunct=this.execChildFunct.bind(this)
  }

  execChildFunct: function() {
  console.log('Managed!');
  }
  return (
   <Child onPress = {this.execChildFunct}></Child>
  )

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Burak! I've improved my explanation of the problem, sorry for not being clear: I know what you are talking about, what I'm trying to do is different. The two functions (child and parent) do also other stuff, I've simplified in order to get clearer. Is there a way to access a child component's function directly?

Comment: What's purpose of `bind` here? While child onPress already use `this`, it means calling its method (execChildFunct) . Why we need to `bind` for this function?

Comment: @TomSawyer In order to use instance variables in execChildFunct, the function must be binded. In this case I just have log in the function. So binding is not mandatory.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy So, it means if we use `this` inside `execChildFunct` => `this` refers to `Child` instance? Purpose of using binding here is to create function named Child.execChildFunct = Parent.execChildFunct?

Comment: @TomSawyer I did not understand what you meant. Assume that this class had states, in order to reach these states in this function you need to bind it. Also if you declare a variable like this.elementX in the constructor for example. you have to bind function to reach this element.

Answer (score 0):

this is my source code for example:

**Child Component:**

```
/* Child.js */
import React from 'react'

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this) //-> important 
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined)
  }
  onChange() {
    alert('ok success')
  }
  render() {
    return <View><Text>Hello World!</Text><View>
  }
}

export default (Child);
```

**Parent Component:**

```
/* Parent.js */
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

class Parent extends React.Component {
  onShow = () => {
    this.child.onChange()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} /> //-> important 
        <Button onPress={()=>this.onShow()} title={"button check"}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

goodluck!