# How to call `this.props.children` 's function from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

There are some question relative, but completely different

[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

[Call child function from parent component in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307610/call-child-function-from-parent-component-in-react-native)

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909

They all need import `Child` in `Parent` file.

But how to set ref to `this.props.children`  ???

### Purpose

I want to call `Child` method in `Parent` , `Parent` is a common wrapper which require a `Child` with specific function .  `Child` is dynamic,

1. Child

   ```
   class Child extends React.Component {
     method() {
       alert(1111);
     }
     render() {

       return (
         <div>
           ....
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Parent

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   // can not import Child here
   // import Child from './Child'  

   class Parent extends React.Component {
     onClick = () => {
       this.props.children.method() // do stuff, but not work
     }
     render() {

       const {children} = this.props;
       return (
         <div>
           {children}
           <button onClick={this.onClick}></button>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. index.js

   ```
   <Parent>
      <Child/ >
   </Parent>
   ```

`Parent` only can access `Child` by `this.props.children`, I don't want  pass `Child`'s method to `Parent` in index.js , or define Child's method in index.js.

In other word:

1. `Child` keep all `Child`'s code.(For example, a form with submit logic)
2. `Parent` is a common wrapper. (For example, a dialog used to wrap a form)
3. Index.js don't care them

Any idea?

Comment: Is `children` an single child in your case. If its so then, its quite easy. If its multiple, then you have to find which one it it..

Comment: It is single. I had tried `this.props.children.handleSubmit()`, but not work. So I ask this question.

Comment: You can use `React.cloneElement` and pass an `ref` to it. Then you can use the ref to access the function from parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Panther 's comment, I work it around by using React.cloneElement :

1. Child

   ```
   class Child extends React.Component {

     handleSubmit() {
       //...
     }

     render() {

       return (
         <div>
           ....
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Parent

   ```
   import React from 'react'

   class Parent extends React.Component {

     onClick() {
       // fist child need have handleSubmit
       this.refs.child0.handleSubmit()
       this.toggleDialog()
     }

     render() {

       const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
         (child, index) => React.cloneElement(child, {
           ref : `child${index}`
         })
        );

       return (
           <div>
             <DialogContent>
               {children}
             </DialogContent>
           <button onClick={this.onClick}></button>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. index.js

   ```
   <Parent>
      <Child/ >
   </Parent>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply like this: (the code was tested!)

Parent.js

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  onClick() {
    // take notice to the array's index "children[0]" (you can also loop the children array)
    this.refs.wrapper.children[0].method();
  }

  render() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    // you must put the ref="wrapper" to locate the container element wrapping all the children
    return (
      <div ref="wrapper">
        {children}
        <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child.js (no change)

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  method() {
    alert(1111);
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        ....
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js: (no change)

```
<Parent>
   <Child/ >
</Parent>
```

Comment: And there is a drawback,  you have to use a dom element instead of a react  component to wrap `children` . Because react  component's may be multi-level, children would be wrong. So I prefer @Panther 's solution.

Comment: OK I see, if you have complicated children structure inside the parent DOM, or if you cannot put "ref" into that parent DOM, then my solution cannot help! But my solution works in other cases, not sure about your current DOM structure, or maybe you applied many other middleware or other react libraries. If I can see your real project's code, I may think of other better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using refs is not recommended. You can use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)
to handle the change in props from the parent or you could use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to handle change in either props or state.

But, in `shouldComponentUpdate` you can easily control the render sequence of the child component.