# React Native - Execute child function from Parent Button onPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

*Disclaimer : I'm new to RN.* I have already tested multiple solutions from other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307610/call-child-function-from-parent-component-in-react-native) without success so far.

I have a Parent that render two Childrens like this

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
       super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Foo name="a" ref={foo => {this.foo = foo}} {...this.props} />
        <Text>-----------</Text>
        <Foo name="b" />
        <Text>-----------</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.foo.myFunction()}
          title="Start"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

My class Foo has a function inside it that start some process :

```
class Foo extends Component {
  myFunction(){
    // Some stuff here
  }
}
```

How can I call this `myFunction` for my Child when I press on the Button ? Optionally, is it possible with only one onPress, to call the function for both Child and avoid creating two Button for each Child ?

Comment: Why even use a child here?  Seems to me you either don't need the child or you could encapsulate all your Foo logic and its components which would make this a non-issue for you.  If you decide you need this arch, then this is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176519/reactjs-call-parent-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child function from parent component in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307610/call-child-function-from-parent-component-in-react-native)

Comment: I tested the solution provided in this question, but it is not working. This is one of the solution that I presented here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what I did is to call a local function when `onPress` and change the state of the Parent. I pass this state to the Child during its creation. And since the Child are updated (if needed) when the Parent's state change this do the trick.

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         activity: false
       }
  }

onButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      activity: !this.state.activity
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Foo name="a" activity={this.state.activity} />
        <Text>-----------</Text>
        <Foo name="b" activity={this.state.activity} />
        <Text>-----------</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.onButtonPress}
          title="Start"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

}





class Foo extends Component {
  myFunction(){
    // Some stuff here
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.activity === true) {
      this.myFunction();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `refs`
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.child.clicked(); }}>
          <Text>Click</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  clicked() {
    alert('clicked');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: getting following error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.child.clicked')

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do `myFunction` logic inside `ParentComponent` and `setState` the data which can be passed into `child` ie:`Foo`.

```
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          fooData: initialValue,
       }
    }


    myFunction = () => {
       // Some stuff here
       this.setState({ fooData: someValue })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Foo name="a" data={this.state.fooData} {...this.props} />
          <Text>-----------</Text>
          <Foo name="b" data={this.state.fooData}/>
          <Text>-----------</Text>
          <Button
            onPress={this.myFunction}
            title="Start"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
```

and you can make the changes inside `Foo` accordingly

```
class Foo extends Component {
      render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return(
          //Use data here to make change
        )
      }
    }
```