# Trigger a function that is inside the child component from the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I trigger a function that is inside the child component from the parent component doing it in the same style as drawer navigation.

They do it like this: `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();`  from the parent

How can I do the same?

Comment: You should post code of what you tried so far.

Comment: I would, but i don't know the correct way to do it to begin with.. its not something i'm trying to solve, but more something i'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you mixed up thing a bit. The example you are showing is an example for triggering a parent component's function from child.

I'll try to clear things up a bit with 2 examples.

**1) Trigger from child:**

To trigger a function of a parent component from a child you can just pass the function as a property to the child component and run it when you need it.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  someFunction = (text) => {
    console.log('Message from child: ', text);
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <Child someProperty={this.someFunction} />
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  _onPress = () => {
    // check if the property is defined and not null
    if(this.props.someProperty) {
      // run the function that is passed from the parent
      this.props.someProperty();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Button onPress={this._onPress} title="Click Me"/>
    )
  }
}
```

**2) Trigger from parent:**

To trigger a function on a child component from parent, you can pass a property that changes when some action happens on the parent component. This will trigger a re-render (in most cases, for more info please take a look at [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)) in child component. You can check the property changes and then do what you need to do in child component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    someParameter: 'someInitialValue',
  }
  someFunction = (text) => {
    this.setState({ someParameter: 'someValue' });
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <Child someProperty={this.state.someParameter} />
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  someFunction = (text) => {
    console.log('Message from parent: ', text);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // Check if the suplied props is changed
    if(prevProps.someProperty !== this.props.someProperty) {
      // run the function with the suplied new property
      this.someFunction(this.props.someProperty);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      {/* ... */}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi bennygenel and thank you its the second one (Trigger from parent ), but what can you use instead of setState??

Comment: Inside my parent there will be only  <Child /> and not  <Child someProperty={this.state.someParameter} />

Comment: @John My intention was to explain you a logic/data flow, since you are asking for a hypothetical project you need to figure the rest for yourself I'm afraid. If you stuck on it when you arrive at that point you can ask more specific question. Since you asked already let me try to answer your question. Why wouldn't there be no passed parameter? Your code is in your control. You can pass a parameter if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any code. Here are my thoughts on the problem.

When you list down a component in a navigator, be it `StackNavigator` or `DrawerNavigator`, the component will receive some props provided by the navigation class itself.

There's an option to send more parameters as props to these navigation objects. Among these extra parameters, can be your one method `toggleDrawer()`.

Also, if you parent component is listed in the navigator and the child component is not. You'll need to explicitly pass the navigation props (`this.props.navigation`) to the child component.
So, when you are inside that child component, all you gotta do is fetch those props and voila, it'll do the needful!

Hope this clarifies out stuff for you.

**EDIT** --- For your third comment

Assumptions:

1. Parent component is listed as `DrawerNavigator({ParentScreen: {screen: ParentScreen}})`
2. There is a `<Route/>` component in `ParentScreen`.

So, what you can do is pass the default navigation props to the `<Route>` component.

Like - `<Route navigation={this.props.navigation} />` and in child component, you can trigger `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()` on any `onPress()` event of any element.

Comment: example for what? there are multiple things listed out in the answer

Comment: I dont quite understand it. Let say you created child 'Router' and used it inside the parent as  <Router />, how can you send from the parent itself his.props.navigation.toggleDrawer(); to fire it from the child

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 parentFunction() {
   this.refs.chid.childFunction(parameterToPassed);
 }

 render () {
   return(
     {/* ... */}
     <Child ref='child' />
     {/* ... */}
   )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  childFunction(text){
    console.log('parameter Passed from parent: ', text);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      {/* ... */}
    )
  }
}
```

Function named as **childFunction** is declared in child component. and called in parent component, inside the function **parentFunction**.

for more information [Call child function from parent component in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307610/call-child-function-from-parent-component-in-react-native?rq=1)