# Call parent function from Child component not working

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have 2 component parent(LoginScreen) and a child(SignupSection). Child component have onClick button. When user click button I need to fire function from the parent component and this is not working for me. I have the following code

**I want Call parent function from Child component**

Parent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Wallpaper from './Wallpaper';
import SignupSection from './SignupSection';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
   }

   childcall()
   {
     alert("hello , this call from child component");
   }

   render() {
     return (
      <Wallpaper>
      <SignupSection 
        childcall ={this.childcall.bind(this)} 
      />
      </Wallpaper>
      );
    }
   }
```

Child

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';


export default class SignupSection extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
    componentWillMount()
    {

    }

    render() {
       return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}  onClick={()=>this.props.childcall()}>Create Account</Text>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Forgot Password?</Text>
          </View>
       );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child function from parent component in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307610/call-child-function-from-parent-component-in-react-native)

Comment: @errorau I want the opposite way I want Call parent function from Child component in React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text does not have `onClick`. There is only `onPress` or you should wrap your text component inside [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) and then call your callback inside `onPress`

Fix :

```
return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}  onPress={()=>this.props.childCall()}>Create Account</Text>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Forgot Password?</Text>
          </View>
       );
```

Comment: thanks it worked but do know why I got this error _this.props.childcall is not a function. (In '_this2.props.childcall()' is undefined) @Vivek_Neel

Comment: you are passing `childCall` and calling `this.props.childcall` check the case.

Comment: @JuniusL. I apologies im kinda new to react native what you mean by check the case?

Comment: childCall not childcall

Comment: @Vivek_Neel I did change everything to childcall Case and i updated the question but im still getting the same error